# check for data transformation oracle etl

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, etl, data-transform

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we validate parent child relationship, compare range of values and validate 
data types as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

*example: T1 is the temporary loading table, And T2 is the new table. we need to make sure that all the data between T1 and T2 is valid with context of range of the value of the variables, the relationships, and data types.*

Thanks, Santosh

Comment: If you could show your tables, then your problem may become clear

Comment: I am sorry. You could leave the parent child relationship part. Just assume them as two standard table. One is a temp table from csv file. The target could be 3 columns with id, date, and age between 0 and 100. would a general query be sufficient. like "select * into exception where age >100.

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate data between two oracle tables following scenarios should be considered-:

1) Data comparison - compare the data between two tables using minus queries.

```
         Select [column names] from tableA
          Minus
          Select [column names] from Table
```

2) Business rules - Verify the data complies to the business rules like in this can age between some range.
You can write negative queries to test such scenarios like

```
Select * from table where (age < x or age > y)
```

3) Data truncation - Make sure data in target database is not truncated. Make sure that is length of target column is not less than source column or the maximum length of data at source side

4)  Data Correctness - Verify that data is not inaccurately recorded, check default values, Field Boundaries, unique Key, Primary key etc.